# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded : Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am executing one Spark SQL query.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE desttable PARTITION(prtition_date,hour) 

select .....from srctable..
```

This query is running inside a thread every 10 minutes. It was working fine, but after 6 hrs. I observed below error message.

```
Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-5" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead 
limit exceeded
22/12/13 19:07:42 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning
+- *HashAggregate
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning
  +- *HashAggregate
     +- *Filter
```

Can someone Please suggest me what is the issue here and How should I resolve this. within 10 min there is not much data I am expecting 1k records in every thread.

sample Code :

```
new Thread(new Runnable {
override def run(): Unit = {
while (true) {
spark.sql(sparksql)
 Thread.sleep(120000)
}
}
}).start()
scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
}
```

This is what I found  on some website

"The java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded error is the JVM’s way of signalling that your application spends too much time doing garbage collection with too little result. By default the JVM is configured to throw this error if it spends more than 98% of the total time doing GC and when after the GC only less than 2% of the heap is recovered."

can some Please suggest some configuration to handle in spark.

Comment: did you try to increase spark executors memory ?

Comment: can you please a basic info about what you are trying to do using the above code, then someone might be able to provide an alternative and efficient approach if there are limitations in this approach

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya I have one kafka Topic and spark streaming job consuming data from kafka and storing in this hive  external table(src table). From there I am doing some aggregation and loading in one more managed table(dest-table). So Executing this query in a thread with 10 min interval which is scanning  the last 2 hrs (2 partition_date) from src table and loading in dest-table(dynamic partition overload)

Comment: @AbdennacerLachiheb 

I did not try. as of now I am using : --num-executors 1,  --driver-cores 1 , --driver-memory 1G , --executor-cores 1 , --executor-memory 1G


IT is in lower environment , so executing with limited resource ,as we have very limited resources available in lower env.(dev/sit).

Please suggest if I can add any other Configuration here.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya @ AbdennacerLachiheb      I have added question with more details and code here. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74806663/exception-in-thread-dispatcher-event-loop-5-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-ove