# Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-5" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded : Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

Could someone please make a suggestion here? I am executing the following code using the spark submit command, which is taking data from the src hive table (hive is taking data from the spark streaming job and the source is Kafka) every 5 minutes and doing some aggregation over the last 2 hours of partition at the target side.

```
val sparksql="insert OVERWRITE table  hivedesttable(partition_date,partition_hour) 
    select "some business logic with aggregation and group by condition" from hivesrctable
    where concat(partitionDate,":",partitionHour) in ${partitionDateHour}"

new Thread(new Runnable {
override def run(): Unit = {
while (true) {
val currentTs = java.time.LocalDateTime.now
var partitionDateHour = (0 until 2)
.map(h => currentTs.minusHours(h))
.map(ts => s"'${ts.toString.substring(0, 10)}${":"}${ts.toString.substring(11,13)}'")
.toList.toString().drop(4)

/** replacing ${partitionDateHour} value in query from current Thread value dynamically*/
  val sparksql=  spark_sql.replace("${partitionDateHour}",partitionDateHour)
  spark.sql(sparksql)
  Thread.sleep(300000)}}}).start()
  scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
```

It was working properly for 5 to 6 hours before displaying the error message below.

```
Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-5" in java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead 
limit exceeded
22/12/13 19:07:42 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning
+- *HashAggregate
+- Exchange hashpartitioning
+- *HashAggregate
+- *Filter
```

My Spark-submit Configuration :

```
--conf "spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true"
--conf "spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict" 
--num-executors 1
--driver-cores 1 
--driver-memory 1G  
--executor-cores 1  
--executor-memory 1G
```

I attempted to increase —executor-memory, but the issue persisted. I'm wondering if there's a way to release all of the GC process's resources after each thread so that unneeded objects and resources can be freed up.

Could someone please advise me on how to handle this situation?

Comment: If you don't have a gc log, get one. I would guess there's a memory leak of some sort in there.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC Overhead limit exceeded` occurs if the Java process is spending more than approximately 98% of its time doing garbage collection and if it is recovering less than 2% of the heap. Read more over [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html).

There could be two possible reasons: (1.) you are having a memory leak - in most of cases this turns out to be the root cause (2.) you are not using sufficient heap memory.

I would suggest do heap dump analysis and see if you have memory leak. Also, try to increase memory and see how it goes.